# Undefined variable $status even though it should work (according to my logic)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this piece of code in one of my files

```php
$status = $this->request->get('status');
            if ($status !== "0") {
                $query = Student::whereHas('statusuri', function($q) {
                    $q->where('stare_stagiu_id', '=', $status);
                })->get();
            }
```

and I get "undefined variable `$status`" and I can't understand why.

From my **POV**, it should 100% work, but I might be missing something.

Why is this error thrown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your closure function($q) you need to inject $status by utilizing `use` statement:

```
 $query = Student::whereHas('statusuri', function($q) use ($status) {
                $q->where('stare_stagiu_id', '=', $status);
            })->get();
```

Comment: It worked. I'll accept the answer ASAP. Is this happening because I'm calling Student::whereHas (basically an external method) and it doesn't have the same scope?

Comment: It’s because you are using a _callback function_ there, and that has its own scope, same as any other function.